# Selection Sort vs. Insertion Sort

Tags: insertion-sort, selection-sort

I'm just wondering, would the speed of selection sort change depending on the TYPE of data? So like would the speed change depending on if it were words or numbers? why or why not?. Also, would the speed of insertion sort change depending on the TYPE of data?

I personally don't think they do change the speed of the sorting but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

A comparison-based sort algorithm needs to know, among other things:

- how to tell if element a is "smaller" than element b or not
- how to swap two elements in the array,
  ie. moving one element to the position of another and vice-versa.

Other than this two things, no part of the algorithm depends on the actual type and/or content of the data elements. The only possible speed difference is in this parts.

Yes, comparing eg. strings is usually slower than comparing integer, and the longer the strings get, the more noticable the difference will be. The same is valid for swapping, altough there are some C++ things to remedy that (depending on the implementation of the data type, swapping could be done by copying everything (slow) or just by swapping eg. a pointer (faster))

Comment: Swapping two elements is also relevant. So is copy-/move-constructing and destructing.

Comment: @Deduplicator so different data types will decrease the speed of selection sort? why?

Comment: @JohnMatthews What he means that moving elements around can take more/less time too, depending on the kind of data, and after all, a sorting algo does move data. Forgot to write that in the answer. (The algorithm itself is still the same.)

Comment: @deviantfan would the same thing apply to insertion sorts?

Comment: @JohnMatthews It is valid for *all* comparison-based sorting algos. Btw., updated the answer.